# How do I implement keras mnist model with video camera

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, mnist

I have successfully build an model of handwritten digits. How would I load the model and use it with live data coming from a video camera? I would like it to draw a box around the number and label the number.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems.  This question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad however there might be one video to answer all your qestions.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFWKdLOxykE) is how use an ml model on your Android.